# Loadrunner 12 - TruClient IE & FireFox Issues

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, loadrunner, truclient

Having the below issues using the TruClient Protocols. Any help would be much appreciated.

Set Up: I have Loadrunner 12 installed in Win7 with IE 11 & latest version of Firefox (32.0) installed.

**Question 1:**

When I record a script using "TruClient Ajax IE" protocol I get an error as below:

When I click on Develop Script I get this error:

> In order to edit an Ajax TruClient IE script you must have Internet Explorer 9,10  or 11 installed on your machine. VUGen could not start TruClient browser to enable you to develop your script.

**Question 2:**

When I record a script using "TruClient Ajax Firefox" I am able to record a flow but one of the components to download records does not even show up in screen. So unable to record it.

**Question 3:**

When I used the "TruClient Ajax Firefox" protocol to upload a file from my local machine once I point to the file and click upload, nothing happens while recording. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have IE9 or higher installed on the system.

2 & 3. Make sure that the AUT works outside LoadRunner, with the same version of FF browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question and you may already have an answer, but:

> Question 2:
>
> When I record a script using "TruClient Ajax Firefox" I am able to record a flow but one of the components to download records does not even show up in screen. So unable to record it.

You don't say what kind of component this is, but I'm assuming a Java applet.  If so, you may need to enable it to be displayed.  Under 11.5, this can be done from `Vugen->Tools->TruClient Settings` by selecting `Extensions` (we're just now updating our environment to 12, so it may have moved).

However - TruClient doesn't support recording for Java apps or applets, so the point is moot.  You should be able to record it and play it back from within the browser (at least, that was my experience with Vugen 11.5), but when you exit the recorder you won't be able to successfully replay.  I banged my head against the wall on this one for quite awhile before I figured it out, and even longer before I accepted it.  According to a post in the HP Community Knowledgebase:

> ...AJAX TC is more of a javascripting tool so applets arent supported but if
>   you go to `Vugen->Tools->TruClient Settings` and go to  `Extensions` and you
>   can enable extensions here.

The full thread is located [here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/LR11-52-TruClient-Firefox-support-java-applet-during-recording/td-p/6189207#.VQrq7OHA52E%22here%22), but it doesn't say much more than that.

This may also be the reason you're experiencing the issue you're having regarding **Question 3**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running script on your machine then. I suggest placing file in **“C:\temp”** before recording. (Go to "Run" >> write "%temp%" will get the path where to keep your "File" **IF** its not working go to >> Run >> write  "temp" . Add that file over here and go for recording and "Play the script")

While recording upload the file from the above location as i told you.

```
 web_submit_data("AddAttachment.aspx",
 "Action=https://learningshared.com/AddAttachment.aspx",
 "Method=POST",
 "EncType=multipart/form-data",
 "RecContentType=text/html",
 "Snapshot=t7.inf",
 "Mode=HTML",
 ITEMDATA,
     "Name=__VIEWSTATE", "Value={ViewState_Value_1}", ENDITEM,
     "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION", "Value={EVENTVALIDATION_1}", ENDITEM,
     "Name=FileUpload1", "Value=C:\\Temp\\my_uploaded_file.pdf", "File=yes", ENDITEM,
     "Name=Button1", "Value=Upload", ENDITEM,
 LAST);
```

Always give double back slash because its "C Lang" in Loadrunner.

For More check out the Links will help you 
[check Link for Upload](http://loadrunnerinterviewquestionsa2z.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-upload-files-in-scripting-load.html)

[upload file in LR](http://easyloadrunner.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-upload-files-in-scripting-load.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question,

> Question 1:
>
> When I record a script using "TruClient Ajax IE" protocol I get an error as below:
>
> When I click on Develop Script I get error - In order to edit an Ajax TruClient IE script you must have Internet Explorer 9,10 or 11 installed on your machine. VUGen could not start TruClient browser to enable you to develop your script.

Try launch VuGen by "Run as administrator".

Answer (score -1):

Load runner 12 supports Firefox version till 23

As a result the events not able to record.

Can you try with lower version